# Why use React server side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just learned react recently and intend to use it for my next project. I have come across react server side rendering for a few times, but wonders why do we still need it in "modern age".

In this [article](http://unwttng.com/react-server-side-rendering/), it argues that with server side rendering, user does not have to wait to load those js from CDN or somewhere to see the initial static page, and the page will resume functionality when js arrives.

But after building with webpack production configuration, and gzip, the whole bundle (with react, my code and a lot other stuff) only takes 40kb, and I have aws CDN for it. I don't quite see the reason to use server side rendering for my situation.

So the question is why people still use server side rendering if the resulting javascript bundle is so tiny after gzip?

Comment: Complicated websites can take a relatively long time to render on the client, particularly mobile clients. Having a pre-rendered version to start with can reduce this delay.

Comment: Minimizes client's perception of network latency and boosts SEO.

Comment: Definitely agree with @Shashank, search engines can't yet index applications that are totally js-driven.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Load Times

A rendered view of the application can be delivered in the response of the initial HTTP request. In a traditional single page web app, the first request would come back, the browser would parse the HTML, then make subsequent requests for the scripts — which would eventually render the page. Those requests will still happen, but they won't ever get in the way of the user seeing the initial data.

This doesn't make much difference on quick internet connections, but for users on mobiles in low network coverage areas, this initial rendering of data can make apps render 20-30 seconds faster.

Views with static data can also be cached at a network level, meaning that a rendered view of a React application can be served with very little computational overhead

### SEO

When a search engine crawler arrives at a web page, the HTML is served and the static content is inspected and indexed. In a purely client side Javascript application, there is no static content. It is all created and injected dynamically once the appropriate scripts load and run.

Unlike React, most frameworks have no way of serialising their component graph to HTML and then reinflating it. They have to use [a more convoluted approach](https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo), which often involves rendering their page in a headless browser at the server, then serving up that version whenever a crawler requests it.

React can just render the component tree to a HTML string from a server side JS environment such as Node.js, then serve that straight away. No need for headless browsers or extra complications.

### Noscript

It also allows you to write applications which [gracefully degrade](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation_versus_progressive_enhancement) and ultimately, can be used as thin clients. This means that the processing goes on at the server and the application can be used in a browser with Javascript disabled. Whether or not that's an important market to consider is a debate for another time.

Comment: Found this post pretty useful with example for react on server side https://www.akshatpaul.com/blog/2015/server-side-with-react/

Answer (score 1):

## All-or-none rendering

This is a UX concern, some designers decide they don't like incremental rendering. The designer wants the page to show up complete and perfect, without the loading spinner, insertion of fetched text here and there, and displacement of layout.

*Scroll bar restoration* is a difficult issue for client side rendering. See [Keep scroll position when navigating back](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10929) (When navigating forward and then back, the scroll position is lost).  Server side rendering does not suffer from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you're chasing SEO will better rendered on server.
so all contents will read by bot SEO.

Comment: Would it be enough to just render initialState() on server and other stuff on client side for each entry point and SEO bot can still find my site?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to SEO mentioned above, with SSR browser could present the page right away even before all Java Script files are loaded. I have a [tutorial](https://www.toni-develops.com/2018/09/10/server-side-rendering/) explaining this.