# How server side rendering help crawlers? and which is better server side rendering or client side rendering?

Tags: angular, reactjs, web-crawler, google-crawlers

i was reading angular docs of server side rendering with angular in that they mention that server side rendering is help crawlers. i knew that in server side rendering crawlers can get whole dom but crawlers can also interact with the components then how it can help crawlers? and which is better server side  rendering or client side rendering on security point of view? i also read same thing for react

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use React server side rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948119/why-use-react-server-side-rendering)

Answer (score 0):

When you only have **client-side rendering**, accessing the web application means downloading all static assets (HTML, CSS, JS) and waiting for JS code to render the page. After rendering, the whole DOM tree exists. This process is **slow and time-consuming**.

**Server-side rendering** helps with crawlers because then they **immediately** get the most important information on the page which they need. Other parts of the page, which are not so important for crawlers, can then stay as client-side rendering.