# Link sharing in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

When I share link such as https://example/about-us, https://example/home, https://example/contact-us. The description popup which comes up will show AboutUs | Example, Home | Example, Contact Us | Example.

I have used react-helmet but it is updating the title but not the link popup description. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlrYO.png)

Comment: `react-helmet` is only for dynamically updating `<head>` elements while rendering your components. When you preview the URL, only `index.html` in your `/public` folder is loaded. You might need to refer: https://ogp.me/

Comment: <Helmet>
        <title>Contact Us | CBSol</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Learn about CBSol's mission and values" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="Contact Us | CBSol" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="Learn about CBSol's mission and values" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.cbsolpro.com//contact-us-image.jpg" />
      </Helmet>

Comment: i have used it like that

Comment: You might need to use Server SIde Rendering. Refer SEO in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948119/why-use-react-server-side-rendering